# Get values in numpy array either side of a specified value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I have a numpy array, provided at random, which for this example looks like:

```
a = [10, 8, 6, 4, 2, -2, -4, -6, -8, -10, 1]
```

ideally, in this example, the values would be between -10 and 10 but this cannot be guaranteed (as above).

I want to retrive the 2 values closest to zero, such that:

```
b = a[a > 0][-1] 

c = a[a < 0][0]
```

which would ideally return me the values of 2 and -2. However, the 1 value is included in the slice in b and i get returned the values of 1 and -2.

Is there a way in numpy to retrieve the values immediately 'next' to zero?

Its worth noting that whilst I always want to split the array at 0, the array could be any length and I could have an uneven number of positive and negative values in the array (i.e. [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1])

A real world example is:

[image]

I want the yellow and green position but get returned the blue and green position instead, as the data crosses back over zero from -ve to +ve

Comment: Thought I could use the index position of 0 and go from there, then realized I didn't have a 0 value. Ive edited the post to reflect this (thanks to those that also suggested this)

Comment: Not clear about the definition. Firstly, shouldn't `1` be the closest value that is close to `0` in the first example;  in the second example should you return `0` or `1` `-1`?;

Comment: What should be returned in your first example, ``[2, -2]``, ``[-10, 1]``, or both? Can we assume that the numbers are monotonically decreasing?

Comment: I need the values of -2 and 2 to be returned where the value of 1 is an anomaly (in the 2nd example I would want 1 and -1). It can't be assumed that the values are monotonically decreasing. Will add a figure

Comment: Can an anomaly occur at the beginning of the series?

Comment: yes, its the output from the first derivative of some data so its dependent on the input data where the inflection point occurs. Im just interested in the two values closest to zero in the trend (i.e. not anomalies)

Comment: "Is there a way in numpy to retrieve the values immediately 'next' to zero?" What's wrong with the simple `np.abs(a).min()` approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function should do the job:

```
import numpy as np
def my_func(x):
    left = np.where(x[:-1]>0)[0][-1]
    right = 1 + np.where(x[1:]<0)[0][0]
    return x[left], x[right]
```

Demo:

```
>>> a = np.array([10, 8, 6, 4, 2, -2, -4, -6, -8, -10, 1])
>>> b = np.array([5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1])
>>> my_func(a)
(2, -2)
>>> my_func(b)
(1, -1)
```

Comment: It works. Hopefully there are no other scenarios that creep up and break it. I will test it and see